# Ubuntu Apache can't access cgi-bin folder

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, cgi

I created a droplet on DigitalOcean but can not run the python scripts in cgi-bin folder. I tried

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
chmod a+rwx cgi-bin
```

Also give chmod 755 to files but It did not work. When I try to acces cgi-bin folder it gives Forbidden error and says `You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/ on this server.` Can any one help?

My config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/test/cgi-bin/"
    <Directory /var/www/test/cgi-bin/>
            AllowOverride All
            Options ExecCGI
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .tcl .py
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/test/">
            AllowOverride All
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test"

</VirtualHost>
```

Also I created a test python file in document root and when I opened it, it behaves like a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the following lines to your `httpd.conf` or you web-server config file

```
<Files ~ "\.(py|cgi)$">
    SetHandler python-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</Files>
```

See Also : [mod-python](http://modpython.org/)